# Regex Input Validation Limit to maximum no. of commas

Tags: regex

I am running jQuery Autocomplete with a Laravel form field.

It grabs data from my db

```
Specialty Area Examples: Real Estate, Mortgage Lenders, Renovation, Buyer's Agent, Listing Agent, Relocation, Short-Sale, Consulting, Local Experts, Refinancing, Architecture, Home Building, Carpentry, Electrical, Engineering, Interior Design, Landscaping, Painting, Plumbing, Appraisal, Commercial Property, Insurance, Legal, Conveyancing,
```

Users can type in one of the examples and the autocomplete will complete the rest in the field.

I want to limit the user to being allowed to input a maximum of 4 Specialty Area Examples into the form field. So a user can type in for example:

Real Estate, Short-Sale, Consulting, Local Experts

After that the user should not be allowed to input more data.  So the maximum number of commas I need to set in the form field is 3.

Comment: And if the user will not use commas ? That's not the way to do it: implement tags (like those we have here at SO) and limit the number of tags to 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#txtBox").keypress(function (e) {
    var input = $(this).val() + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if (input.split(',').length > 4) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Demo: <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/y6eQF/</kbd>

Comment: Hi Vinod, when I try and copy it into my autocomplete script, the form field freezes after the 4th comma, so that the user cannot delete or edit the field anymore.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22370840/jquery-autocomplete-with-input-validation-frozen

Answer (score 0):

This RegEx should do what you want: `([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\ \'\"]+\,){3}[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\ \'\"]+`

You can also do it with `split()` as Vinod mentioned. In PHP you have `split()/explode()` as well.

Comment: Hi Babar, I get this error 
ErrorException

preg_match(): Unknown modifier '{'

when I use laravel's regex validator